# JavaScript form (ajax submission) with validation doing something funky

Tags: javascript, html, validation, post, jquery-ajax

I am trying to do a form validation function with Ajax submission. For some reason the validation doesn't work and when it submits, my server gets the empty fields (when I am testing for the validation) but it shows that it tried to post to the same page... I don't know why.

Form:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form id='form' novalidate method="post" class='m-2 p-1'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input required type="text" name='First Name' class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        <label for="fname">First Name<span class='red' aria-label='required'> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input required type="text" name='Last Name' class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input required type="email" name='Email' class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <label for="lname">Email <span class='red' aria-label='required'> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <select required name='Reason For Contacting' class="form-control" id="reason" placeholder="Reason For Contacting">
          <option value='Feedback' selected>Feedback</option>
          <option value='other'>Other</option>
        </select>
        <label for="why">Reason For Contacting<span class='red' aria-label='required'> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <textarea required name='Comments' class="form-control" id="comment" placeholder="Your Comments"></textarea>
        <label for="comment">Your Comments<span class='red' aria-label='required'> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col p-1'>
      <button class='form-control btn btn-outline-primary' id='submit'>Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My JS File:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  autosize($('textarea'))
  $('#submit').click((e) => {
    if (validate() == true) {
      sendForm();
    } else {
      error(validate())
    }
  })
})
var errors;
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
  alert('Error message: ' + msg + '\nURL: ' + url + '\nLine Number: ' + linenumber);
  return true;
}

function validate() {
  elements = $(':input')
  elements.each((element) => {
    element = $(element).get()
    if (element.value === '' || !email(element)) {
      errors += element.name + " is invalid."
    } else {
      return;
    }
  })
  if (errors) {
    return errors
  } else true;
}

function sendForm() {
  name = $('input[name="First Name"]').val().trim() + " " + $('input[name="Last Name"]').val().trim()
  email = $('input[name="Email"]').val().trim()
  why = $("select").val().trim()
  comments = $('textarea').val().trim()
  data = {
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
    "reason": why,
    "text": comments
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://admin.bekesbikes.tk/contact',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      new Notify({
        title: 'Submitted!',
        text: 'Your feedback has been recorded!\n\nWe will get back to your email shortly!\n\nHope to see you soon!',
        effect: 'slide',
        status: 'success',
        speed: 1000,
        autoclose: true
      })
      $(':input').val('');
      $('select').val('Feedback')
    },
    error: (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      new Notify({
        title: 'Could not submit!',
        text: 'The form could not be submitted.\n\nPlease try again or come back later!\n\nSorry for the inconvenience.',
        effect: 'slide',
        customIcon: "<img src='https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/753/753345.svg?token=exp=1616679486~hmac=4f66bb69b263e9e4d9be5038a16cc41d' width='50px'>",
        status: 'error',
        speed: 1000,
        autoclose: true
      })
    }
  });
}

function error(text) {
  new Notify({
    title: 'Form Fields Are Not Correct',
    text: text,
    effect: 'slide',
    status: 'info',
    speed: 1000,
    autoclose: true
  })
}

function send() {
  if (validate()) {
    sendForm()
  } else {
    error(validate())
  }
}

function email(element) {
  if (element.type === 'email' && /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+$/.text(element.value)) {
    return true;
  } else if (element.type !== 'email') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Where I go when I submit (the form is at this URL):
[image: Where I go when I submit (the form is at this URL):]

Any Idea what I should do? I am using `node.js` with `express.js`.

I added: `e.preventDefault()` to my submit event handler but now when I submit the form without filling in anything, I get this notification:

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you prevent the form from submitting via HTML.  I would expect e.preventDefault() in your submit click handler.

Comment: @James Yep! Now after I added that I get a weird notification... Could you look at my edit in my question? Thanks!

Comment: The value you pass in to error is undefined.  `else true` is not valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your click handler:

- default prevention,
- validate() as variable so that it runs only once,

the errors declaration

- empty string instead of undefined,

your validate() function

- excluded button using :not(),
- changed arrow function to ordinary anonymous function,
- used this instead of element, which was only an index,
- added a return to the last else,

and your email() function

- sourced the email validation out to an own function.

I also deleted send(), as it was not used, declared the variables in sendForm() with var and added many semicolons -> maybe in your code one is already missing and you are hoping that the js error correction will add them automatically...

Finally i added the param **showIcon** to your Notify objects (that was the 'undefined' part ;)

```
$(document).ready(() => {

  autosize($('textarea'))
    
    $('#form').submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var validated = validate();
        if (validated == true) {
            sendForm();
        } else error(validated);
    });
    
    var errors = '';

    window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
        alert('Error message: ' + msg + '\nURL: ' + url + '\nLine Number: ' + linenumber);
        return true;
    }

    function validate() {
        elements = $(':input:not(button)');
        elements.each(function() {
            if (this.value === '' || !email(this)) {
                errors += this.name + " is invalid.";
            } else return;
        });
        if (errors) {
            return errors;
        } else return true;
    }

    function sendForm() {
        var name = $('input[name="First Name"]').val().trim() + " " + $('input[name="Last Name"]').val().trim();
        var email = $('input[name="Email"]').val().trim();
        var why = $("select").val().trim();
        var comments = $('textarea').val().trim();
        var data = {
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "reason": why,
            "text": comments
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://admin.bekesbikes.tk/contact',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
                new Notify({
                    title: 'Submitted!',
                    text: 'Your feedback has been recorded!\n\nWe will get back to your email shortly!\n\nHope to see you soon!',
                    effect: 'slide',
                    status: 'success',
                    speed: 1000,
                    autoclose: true,
                    showIcon: false
                });
                $(':input').val('');
                $('select').val('Feedback');
            },
            error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                new Notify({
                    title: 'Could not submit!',
                    text: 'The form could not be submitted.\n\nPlease try again or come back later!\n\nSorry for the inconvenience.',
                    effect: 'slide',
                    customIcon: "<img src='https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/753/753345.svg?token=exp=1616679486~hmac=4f66bb69b263e9e4d9be5038a16cc41d' width='50px'>",
                    status: 'error',
                    speed: 1000,
                    autoclose: true,
                    showIcon: true
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function error(text) {
        new Notify({
            title: 'Form Fields Are Not Correct',
            text: text,
            effect: 'slide',
            status: 'info',
            speed: 1000,
            autoclose: true,
            showIcon: false
        })
    }

    function validateEmail(email) {
        const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    function email(element) {
        if (element.type === 'email' && validateEmail(element.value)) {
            return true;
        } else if (element.type !== 'email') {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
    
});
```

Comment: I changed the functions and now the same thing happens...

Comment: Ah, yes i changed the errors declaration ```var errors = '';``` -> edited my answer...

Comment: But this must happen in the Notify object: in the text variable from your error function is no undefined. Where comes this Notify from?

Comment: It is a library I found... More info here: https://www.cssscript.com/categories/notification/

Comment: i updated my answer (semicolons and declaration with var) and would like to know which is the one library you used - on cssscript.com (your link) are many libraries for notification listed

Comment: The first one: https://www.cssscript.com/toast-simple-notify/

Comment: It was the showIcon param, that was missing. I found the info at the github page https://github.com/dgknca/simple-notify   (i also updated the code in my answer)...

Comment: Then copy and paste all the code from my answer and try again (it is now the whole js file and not just snippets) - It works for both success and error! ---- i used for css and js the cdn links like recommended at the github page...

Comment: I did... You can test here: https://www.bekesbikes.tk/Contact/

Comment: I test it by just hitting send without filling out anything!

Comment: Yes the whole page content is replaced with the message ```Cannot POST /Contact/``` - Are you sure, that your ajax request points at the correct php file?

Comment: It is node.js and yes... See: `url: 'https://admin.bekesbikes.tk/contact',` in the ajax...

Comment: If you mean the validate() function then comment it out - does it work in this case? If not can you post your node.js code?

Comment: When i submit the form from my PC with all fields filled, i get the succes notification - i copied your html code in my test.html file and my js code from here in my test.js file - in the html file i have the cdn link to the notification css from the github page in the head and the **js file** from the github page on the **bottom of the body** before my test.js file - you should see my message i have send to you (Max Mustermann)...

Comment: Nope... i didn't get it... Tomorrow I will share my latest code with you using some online code sharing thing...

Comment: your scripts are in the head -  move them to the bottom of the body...

Comment: Did you try to give the data (as string) from node.js back as response? Till now the response data only says 'true'...

Comment: you have another form in your nav with the same id 'form' -> rename it to maybe 'nav_form' and change your elements collection in validate() to ```elements = $('#form :input:not(button)');``` - i tried your html code from bekesbikes.tk/Contact/ and after fixing the two form issues i got the success notification...

Comment: Maybe it fails because 'admin.bekesbikes.tk' is a subdomain. Unfortunately jsonp can't help here to solve the cross-domain restriction since it is only for get requests. Maybe you should try to place the recieving logic in the same domain without 'admin'...

Comment: Ok... after doing the form ids issue (my bad) it submits.... but it doesn't validate... arghh!!!

Comment: its because you forgot the space between #form and :input...